# Still unable to get Spree installed on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

I've been having a hard time trying to get spree to install on rails. I've tried everything and googled like crazy with tons of fresh install, but still can't get it working. Can someone help me out? This is the method I've used and got the furthest out of all my fresh installs.

1. Install ruby 2.0.0
2. Install rails 4.0.4
3. Added gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree', branch: '2-2-stable' to gemfile and bundled
4. Added gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise', branch: '2-2-stable' and bundled.
5. Tried running rails g spree:install --sample=false --seed=false
   and it returns a bunch of errors

   undefined method `configure' for # (NoMethodError)

Tried a bunch of stuff like just using rails g spree:install but still return errors

Help please!

Comment: always provide a full stacktrace. it's the single most useful information you can give!

Comment: Have you tried the Spree getting started tutorial?  http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html

Comment: yep tried, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
$ rvm install 2.1.2
$ gem install rails --version 4.0.5
$ gem install spree
$ spree --version
#=> 2.2.2
$ rails new app
$ cd app
```

Add `spree_auth_devise` and `spree_gateway` with the `2-2-stable` branch. Don't bundle just yet.

```
$ spree install --git 'https://github.com/spree/spree.git' --branch '2-2-stable' --sample false --seed false
```

Say no to auth and gateway.

Please update your question with the error message if you get one. This is a painful process.